# how to trigger ExceptionMapper in jersey 2?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have a problem with my ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
@Component
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    public GenericExceptionMapper() {
        logger.debug("hej hopp");

    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage("Technical error", 
            "An unknown technical error occured.");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(errorMessage).build();
    }
}
```

It doesn't catch any exceptions from my resources. I have placed a debug point in the constructor and see that it is created. I have debuged the request and it doesn't seem to look for any exception handlers.

This is part of my configuration:

```
@ComponentScan("com.companywhereiwork.application")
```

And another part:

```
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", 
               "com.companywhereiwork.application");
```

When I throw an exception from inside one of my resources:

```
    if (Math.random() < 1f) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Blä");
    }
```

It is returned to the client as a tomcat errorpage. It doesn't enter my errorhandler.

[image: postman errorpage]

Comment: Did you add an SOP to see if the toResponse is being called?

Comment: Also if you want to avoid the client ever seeing the tomcat error page, you should probably set the ini-param `jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError` to `true`

Comment: I used a breakpoint (and real logging). It wasn't called. Only the constructor is called.

Comment: Another thing, just because it's created doesn't mean it's registered with Jersey. It could've been created by Spring because of the `@Component` annotation. Is the mapper in the `com.companywhereiwork.application` package or a subpackage? You don't really need it to be managed by Spring. You aren't trying to inject anything

Comment: Yes, good comment (thanks for your effort). The constructor is entered with only the @Provider annotation present. I'm not sure how to check if it really is registered with jersey.

Comment: If it's created through scanning, then it is registered. Don't really have any more ideas

Comment: The ExceptioMapper is in the same package as the Resource. It is in the exact same package as what I set as jersey.config.provider.packages.

Comment: You think you can reproduce the problem into a small GitHub project I can test out. I'm curious to see how this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the @Component annotation. For some reason, the ExceptionMapperFactory didn't pick up my class when it had double annotations like this. I didn't think it would be a problem, but it was. It now works (and I know a little more about the ExceptionMapperFactory).

Comment: It seems a bug in jersey https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2651, fixed in 2.15 which version are you using?

Comment: That was probably it. The version was 2.8.